# How can we orient light in vacuum?

Tags: visible-light, vacuum

Let's consider the mirror clock used to show time dilation in special relativity:

In the rest frame of the clock, the light pulse from the laser pen propagates in vertical direction down then up:

[image]

In the other inertial frame, light moves in oblique straight lines:

[image]

My question is not about time dilation, but rather about predicting the direction of propagation of light.

To be more clear, imagine the mirror clock was moving in a materialistic medium and the laser pen emitting a sound pulse instead of light, then the direction of the pulse will be vertical in the rest frame of the medium and oblique in the mirror's frame. In the case of light, we can't have a rest frame of vacuum, so how do we determine the direction of light ? Does it depend on the motion of the source ?

Comment: @NeuroFuzzy Sorry, I meant a sound pulse that have a unique direction (planar wave front) as a laser beam, not a spherical wave.

Comment: The vacuum doesn't have a rest frame, only matter can define rest frames.

Comment: @CuriousOne well I've already stated this in the question

Comment: Then why are you not using what you have stated and use matter?